# koRpus with German texts: Encoding issue

Tags: r

I am trying to use koRpus for its rich variety of readability measurements, but I am not able to get the German umlauts right.

```
library(koRpus)
txt1 <- treetag("data/txt1.txt", treetagger="manual", lang="de", 
    TT.options=list(path="C:/TreeTagger", preset="de-utf8"))
slot(txt1, "TT.res")
```

works, but the umlauts are "funny":

```
              token   tag          lemma lttr      wclass
1          SchÃ¼ler    NN       SchÃ¼ler    8        noun
2           mussten VMFIN        mÃ¼ssen    7        verb
3         auÃŸerdem   ADV      auÃŸerdem    9      adverb
...
```

The file is UTF-8; the tm-package works perfectly fine with the same input file (but I understand that there is no conversion between tm and koRpus...):

```
library(tm)
txt2 <- VCorpus(DirSource("C:/mini/data/", encoding="UTF-8"), 
    readerControl=list(language="ger"))
inspect(txt2)

<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
Schüler mussten außerdem bloggen und sich mit Margaret Thatcher und Höhlenmalereien beschäftigen
```

I would be deeply grateful for suggestions!

Comment: Try `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "de_DE.UTF-8")`

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem and solved it with re-encoding the vector to UTF-8 even though it already was UTF-8

```
Encoding(txt1) <- "UTF-8"
```

Don't know if this helps...

Comment: Unfortunately 
    Encoding() 
works only with character-vectors, not with objects of the class "kRp.tagged".

Comment: Are there any updates on this? I ran into the same error today..

Comment: My advice is to use `quanteda`, which has an even bigger set of readability measures: https://quanteda.io/reference/textstat_readability.html. I wouldn't trust a package which manages to mess up encoding (which is why I moved away from `tm` as well).